# creating a migration for this relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, migration, relationship

I completly forgot, over night, how to create the migration for this type of relationship:

I have a project table and a user table and each user has their own projects that they create how ever users may share the project they create either upon creating or editin the project so the relation ship is:

each project may have many users and belongs to user while each user has many projects and belongs to a project.

the problem?

I am not sure how to make a migration from this >.> as I was told I need to create a new table to stipulate this relationship.

I was thinking

```
generate migration project_user project_id :int user_id :int
```

is that any where right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a total of 3 tables: users, projects, and project_editor_links

Your migrations:

```
create_table :users do |t|
  # user stuff
end

create_table :projects do |t|
  t.references :user
  # project stuff
end

create_table :project_editor_links |t|
  t.references :user
  t.references :project
end
```

To generate that last table from the command-line:

```
rails g migration project_editor_links project:references user:references
```

Your models should look something like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :projects
  has_many :project_editor_links
  has_many :edited_projects, :through => :project_editor_links
end

class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :project_editor_links
  has_many :editors, :through => :project_editor_links
end

class ProjectEditorLinks < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :editor, :class_name => 'User', :foreign_key => :user_id
  belongs_to :edited_project, :class_name => 'Project', :foreign_key => :project_id
end
```

Comment: I got the first-two tables its the third I am confused about. whats :references? foriegn key?

Comment: See [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html#special_helpers).  `model:references` is basically the same as `model_id:integer` unless the relationship is polymorphic.  So, no it won't add a foreign key (at this time); its only advantage is readability.